# OpenID provider library recommendations for PHP

Tags: php, openid, openid-provider, stackexchange

Our PHP site uses a home-grown forms auth implementation. We're considering making our site into an OpenID provider so that we can authenticate (using our exisitng user accounts) users on a [StackExchange](http://stackexchange.com) site.  If we have to add code or UI to our login form or add fields to our database, that's fine-- we just don't want to have to rip out what we have and replace it all in order to get OpenID provider support.

There are several libraries for PHP [linked on the OpenID website](http://openid.net/developers/libraries/#php).  Anyone have experience with using any of these libraries to adding OpenID provider capability to a PHP site, and if so which is your favorite and why?  Are there particular libraries you would stay away from, and if so, why?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, *most* of the options listed on that page don't have provider support, so I think your options come down to [OpenID Enabled's php-openid](http://openidenabled.com/php-openid/) or Zend_OpenId.  I'm partial to the openidenabled libraries myself, but then again, I was on the team that wrote them.  php-openid is generally compatible with a wider range of PHP versions, and its test coverage is pretty extensive.

I don't really know much about the Zend offering, but it might be appropriate if you're fortunate enough to not need PHP 4 compatibility and like that framework thing they do.

Answer (score 1):

Start with browsing through the official OpenID developer website @ http://openid.net/add-openid/become-a-provider/

There, it gives you three options:

- Outsource to a third-party provider
- Use an existing library or plugin
- Read the specs and OpenID yourself

Option 1 may not be the one you would aiming for, since you want your site to be a provider as you have hinted above.

Option 3 is ok if you have the time and capacity to implement it. Try going through http://openid.net/specs/openid-authentication-2_0.html and see if your development team can stomach that.

Finally, there's option 2, which I think the best choice. There are enough choices of PHP libraries listed in http://openid.net/developers/libraries/#php . I imagine it would be easy to use one of these libraries to extend your existing authentication mechanism to provide OpenID authentication service but I can't be sure as I have not tried any of them yet.

Good luck and godspeed!

Comment: Hah, serves me right for trusting Google's results. Google pointed me to http://wiki.openid.net/Run-your-own-identity-server which shows a few UI-focused options when I was looking for bare libraries. I'm admittedly looking for someone's real-world experiences and feedback from using those libraries, but thanks much for pointing me to that libraries list since it's a step in the right direction!